# Logical Form - Union of a Set containing the Power Set with Predicate/Propositional Function

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

The source is Example 2.3.6.#4 on P78 of *How to Prove It* by Daniel Velleman. Herein,

● $P(...)$ denotes the power set (and NOT probability) of $\cdots$.
● From P75 & 79: $\mathcal{F}$ := a set/family of sets $= \{ \text{ a set } A_i : i \in I \, \}$ where $I$ is some index set.
● From P77: $\bigcup \mathcal{F} = \{x : \color{green}{∃ \, A ∈ \mathcal{F} : x ∈ A} \} = \{x : \color{green}{∃ \, A \, (A ∈ \mathcal{F} ∧ x ∈ A)}\}. $

> Analyse the logical form of:  $X \in \bigcup\{P(A) : A \in \mathcal{F}\}$
>
> **Solution :** This time start by writing out the definition of union, according to which the statement means that $X$ is an element of at least one of the
>   sets $P (A)$, for $A ∈ \mathcal{F}$: ie $∃ \, A ∈ \mathcal{F} \qquad  \; X ∈ P (A) \; . \tag{\checkmark}$
>   Inserting our
>   analysis of the statement $X ∈ P (A)$ from Example 2.3.3, we get $∃\, A ∈
> \mathcal{F} \; \qquad ∀ \, y \,(y ∈ X → y ∈ A). \qquad \blacksquare$

**My attempt :** From the given statement, $X$ is an element of at least one of $\bigcup \, \color{#FF4F00}{\{ P(A) : A \in \mathcal{F}\}}$.
Thus, by the above definition in green, $ \exists \; \color{ #007FFF}{\text{ some set } S} \in  \color{#FF4F00}{[ \, P(A) : A \in \mathcal{F} \, ]} \; \ni \; X \in \color{ #007FFF}{\text{some set } S}$.

Because $S, X$ are both sets, $X \in \color{ #007FFF}{\text{some set } S}$ doesn't make sense. I stop here because my work already differs from the book's $(\checkmark)$. What are the problems?

---

**Supplement to Adriano's Comment dated Sep 10:**

$\large{\text{1.}}$ Could you please explain how and why $S \in \{P : A \in F\} \iff \exists \, A \in F \; \ni \;  S = P \,$?
I replaced the letters in the interest of generality. For example, why not:
$\color{red}{\iff S = P \quad \ni \quad A \in F} \tag{*}$
$\color{red}{\text{ or } \iff S = P \quad \ni \quad \exists \; A \in F} \tag{♦}$

$\large{\text{2.}}$ Does the following recapitulate your comments correctly?

$$ \begin{align}
\exists \; \color{ #007FFF}{\text{ some set } S} \in  \color{#FF4F00}{[ \, P(A) : A \in \mathcal{F} \, ]} \quad & \ni \quad X \in \color{ #007FFF}{\text{some set } S}  \\ 
\iff \exists \, A \in \mathcal{F} \; \ni \;  \color{ #007FFF}{S = P(A)} \quad & \ni \quad X \in \color{ #007FFF}{\text{some set } S} \\
\iff \exists \, A \in \mathcal{F} \quad & \ni \quad X \in \color{ #007FFF}{\text{some set } P(A)} \qquad \blacksquare 
\end{align}$$

Comment: I don't understand the necessity of the colors, and I also don't see why you have to write "some set $S$". We know, that if we quantify with $\exists$ the variable $S$, then $S$ is *some* object, and in this case the context demands that it is a set.

Answer (score 0):

Let's slowly unwrap the definitions.

Define the family of sets $\mathcal{G} = \{P(A) : A \in \mathcal{F}\}$, where $\mathcal{F}$ is some index set. Now suppose that $X  \in \bigcup\mathcal{G}$. Then by your green definition, we know that there exists some $P(A) \in \mathcal{G}$ such that $X \in P(A)$. Note that, by the defintion of the family of sets $\mathcal{G}$, we know that $A \in \mathcal{F}$. Furthermore, note that even though $X$ and $P(A)$ are both sets, we know by the definition of the power set that $P(A)$ is a **set of sets**, so the statement:
$$
\exists A \in \mathcal{F} \quad\text{ such that }\quad X \in P(A)
$$
is well-defined.

Comment: Thanks. I see why this makes sense: $\exists A \in \mathcal{F} \quad\text{ such that }\quad X \in P(A)$.  However, I still don't grok the problems in my attempt. For example, $S$ is a set and NOT a **set of sets**, so $X \in \color{ #007FFF}{\text{some set } S}$ looks invalid?

Comment: $S$ IS a set of sets. Note that $S \in \mathcal{G}$. Hence, since every element in $\mathcal{G}$ is a power set, and since power sets are sets of sets, it follows that so too is $S$.

Comment: Many thanks. I upvoted. I now realise: $\color{#007FFF}{{ S = \text{ one of the arbitrary } P(A)}}$. So now, we have: $ \exists \; \color{ #007FFF}{P(A)} \in  \color{#FF4F00}{[ \, P(A) : A \in \mathcal{F} \, ]} \; \ni \; X \in \color{#007FFF}{P(A)}$. But how does this become $ ∃ \, A ∈ \mathcal{F} \; :  \; X ∈ P (A) \; ?$  I can see that the last part is the same.

Comment: Note that $S \in \{P(A) : A \in \mathcal{F}\}$ if and only if $\exists A \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $S=P(A)$. But we know that $X \in S$. Hence, we can replace this $S$ with $P(A)$ to obtain:
$$
\exists A \in \mathcal{F} \quad\text{ such that }\quad X \in P(A)
$$

Comment: Many thanks again. Sorry for taking your time. Would you mind looking at my supplement in my OP? I wrote it there for easier reading.