# Rewrite without Set Notation: Element in Set with Variable and Predicate (Velleman, P74)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> [Adriano's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/478979/53259) avouches: $\quad S \in \{\color{#B8860B}{P(A)} : \color{#009900}{A\in\mathscr{F}} \} \iff \exists \;  \color{#009900}{A\in\mathscr{F}} \; \ni \; S \color{#FF2400}{=} \color{#B8860B}{P(A)} \quad \; \;   (\checkmark) $

$\text{My attempt to generalise $(\checkmark)$ :} \quad {S \in \{\color{#B8860B}{B} : \color{#009900}{C \in D} \} \iff \exists \; \color{#009900}{C \in D}\; \ni \;  S \color{#FF2400}{=} \color{#B8860B}{B}} \tag{*}$

$\large{\text{1.}}$ How could the LHS of $(*)$ be unscrambled to the RHS of $(*)$? I'd like to intuit $(*)$ and not relent to or knuckle under it as the definition. For example, why not some other permutation of $A = B$ and $\ni$ and $\exists$ and $C = D $, like the following in purple?

$\color{purple}{\iff A = B \quad \ni \quad C \in D} \qquad \text{ or } \qquad \color{purple}{\iff A = B \quad \ni \quad \exists \; C \in D} \tag{1, 2}$
$\color{purple}{\iff C = D \quad \ni \quad \; A \in B} \qquad \text{ or } \qquad \color{purple}{\iff C = D \quad \ni \quad \exists \; A \in B} \tag{3, 4}$

$\large{\text{2.}}$ What's the genesis or motivation of the $\exists$ on the RHS of $(*), (\checkmark)$? Their LHS don't subsume it?

---

**Supplementary to Prof Scott's Answer:** Prof Scott presents in his Answer,  $(\dagger)$ and $(\ddagger)$:

$X\in\bigcup \, \{\color{#B8860B}{ \, \wp(A)}: \color{#009900}{A\in\mathscr{F} \,}\}\; \quad \iff \quad \exists \; \color{#009900}{A\in\mathscr{F} \,} \Big(X \color{#FF2400}{
\in} \color{#B8860B}{\wp(A)} \Big) \tag{$\dagger$}$

$x\in\bigcup \, \{\, \color{#B8860B}{A}:\color{#009900}{\varphi(A)} \,\} \quad \iff \quad \exists \; A \; \big( \color{#009900}{ \, \varphi(A)} \land x \color{#FF2400}{
\in} \color{#B8860B}{A} \, \big) \tag{$\ddagger$}$

${\large{\text{6.}}}$ How does $(\dagger) \Longrightarrow (\ddagger)$ ? I used  $(\dagger)$ to unravel the LHS of $(\ddagger)$. Then the RHS of $(\ddagger)$ should be : $\iff \quad \exists \color{#009900}{ \, \varphi(A)} \, \Big(X \color{#FF2400}{
\in}\color{#B8860B}{A} \Big) \quad := \quad \exists \; \color{#009900}{ \, \varphi(A)} \, \Big(\color{  #009900}{ \, \varphi(A)} \land X \color{#FF2400}{
\in} \color{#B8860B}{A} \, \big) \tag{¿}$

But $(¿) \neq$ RHS of $(\ddagger)$. How and why not?

${\large{\text{7.}}}$ How and why do $(\checkmark)$ and $(*)$ translate into $\color{#FF2400}{
=}$ while $(\dagger)$ and $(\ddagger)$ translate into $\color{#FF2400}{
\in}$ ?
I spy no union in $(\checkmark)$ and $(*)$, but $\cup$ does figure in $(\dagger)$ and $(\ddagger)$.

${\large{\text{8.}}}$ Do the following 3 remedy $(*)$? If not,  how should $(*)$ be emended? $ {S \in \{\color{#B8860B}{B} : \color{#009900}{C(A) \in D} \} \iff \exists \; \color{#009900}{C(A) \in D}\; \ni \;  S \color{#FF2400}{=} \color{#B8860B}{B}} \tag{5}$
$ {S \in \{\color{#B8860B}{B} : \color{#009900}{C \in D(A)} \} \iff \exists \; \color{#009900}{C \in D(A)}\; \ni \;  S \color{#FF2400}{=} \color{#B8860B}{B}} \tag{6}$
$ {S \in \{\color{#B8860B}{B} : \color{#009900}{C(A) \in D(A)} \} \iff \exists \; \color{#009900}{C(A) \in D(A)}\; \ni \;  S \color{#FF2400}{=} \color{#B8860B}{B}} \tag{7}$

Comment: There is nothing that looks like the displayed mixed symbol-salad on p. 74 of either the first or second editions of Velleman,

Comment: @PeterSmith: I referenced it because the grey box might be passed for a paragraph on that page which says: $x ∈ \{ x_i : i ∈ I \}$ means the same thing as $∃ \, i ∈ I ( \, x = x_i \, ).$

Comment: Could the downvoter please account for himself/herself?

Answer (score 2):

Unlike $\exists C\in D(A=B)$, none of the expressions $(1)$-$(4)$ makes sense when translated into English (or any other language).

> $\exists C\in D(A=B)$: There is an element $C$ of the set $D$ such that $A=B$.

That’s a fairly simple declarative sentence. Now look at one of yours, say $(2)$:

> $A=B\owns\exists C\in D$: $A$ equals $B$ such that there is an element $C$ of the set $D$.

That isn’t a sentence at all; it isn’t interpretable as having any meaning, and the same is true of the other three.

**Added:** The existential quantifier in $\exists C\in D(A=B)$ can’t really be explained, because while your $\exists C\in D(A=B)$ has the form as the statement on which you modelled it, it doesn’t actually mean much. I’ll explain the original statement instead:

$$\exists A\in\mathscr{F}\Big(X\in\wp(A)\Big)\tag{1}$$

is given as a translation of $$X\in\bigcup\{\wp(A):A\in\mathscr{F}\}\;.\tag{2}$$ The existential quantifier in $(1)$ arises from the definition of union: $(1)$ is in fact the **definition** of $(2)$. More generally, if $\varphi$ is some property of sets, $x\in\bigcup\{A:\varphi(A)\}$ be definition means that **there is** some $A$ such that

- $\varphi(A)$ is true, and
- $x\in A$;

i.e., that $\exists A\big(\varphi(A)\land x\in A\big)$.

Comment: @LePressentiment: You’re welcome; take a look at the addition to my answer.

Comment: Thank you again, Professor. Can $(1)$ be deduced/rendered from $(2)$ (intuitively/logically) ? I'd like to perceive $(1)$ as a natural "effusion" of $(2)$.

Comment: @LePressentiment: $(1)$ is the definition of $(2)$: $(1)$ is what $(2)$ actually means. Understanding $\bigcup\{\wp(A):A\in\mathscr{F}\}$ **is** translating it into $(1)$.

Comment: Thank you again. Sorry if I've taken too much of your time. I forgot to ask: What was the problem in my grey box? I just renamed sets and the power set in the grey box to $A, B, C, D$?

Comment: @LePressentiment: The problem is that there is no apparent connection between $A$ and $B$ on the one hand and $C$ and $D$ on the other; the form of the statement, on the other hand, indicates that there may be some choices of $A\in B$ such that $C\in D$ and others such that $C\notin D$, which is possible only if $C$ or $D$ depends somehow on the choice of $A$. In the original this is the case: $D$ is the power set of $A$, which depends on the choice of $A$.

Comment: Thank you again. $\Large{4.}$ Could you please elucidate how $A \in \{B : C \in D\}$ indicates that some $A \in B$ satisfy $C \notin D$? Doesn't the predicate $C \in D$ mean that any $A$ in this set must satisfy it? $\Large{5.}$ As respects your last sentence, should $D$ in $(*) = \mathcal{F}$ in $(\checkmark)$ ?

Comment: Also, would you mind if you please modified (1) and (2) in your Answer to found it upon $(\checkmark)$? I realised that this was the source of my confusion (and not Adriano's original Answer).

Comment: @LePressentiment: Apart from the trivial difference that I used $X$, as in the original source, rather than $S$, $(1)$ and $(2)$ **are** based on $(\checkmark)$. // 4. It doesn’t; it implies that $C\in D$ is somehow a condition on members of $B$, hence something that a member of $B$ might or conceivably might not satisfy. The predicate $C\in D$ says only that the object $C$ is an element of the set $D$; as it stands, there is no reason to think that it has any connection with elements of $B$. // 5. Yes.

Comment: My profuse thanks. Could you please incorporate some of your comments into your Answer and then deleting those comments, for ease of reading? I'm still trying to assimilate all this. For instance, my question on D in $(∗)=$ F in $(✓)$ unfolds over three separate comments. I tried to resolve it in your comment on Sep 18, in one instance, but was declined. Thank you very much again.

Comment: I apologise if this consumes too much of your time. If you don't mind, could you please look at Q6 and Q7 and Q8 in my OP? Sadly, I still haven't grasped this material.

Comment: Could you please let me know whether I have your consent to edit your answer all but to integrate your answers therein?