# "There exists ♦" $\quad$ vs $\quad$ "... for some ♦"

Tags: logic

> [Analyse the logical form of:  $X \in \bigcup\{P(A) : A \in \mathcal{F}\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478935/logical-form-union-of-a-set-containing-the-power-set-with-predicate-propositio).
>
> **Solution :** This time start by writing out the definition of union. Then the statement  above means that $X$ is an element of at least one of the
>   sets $P (A)$, for $A ∈ \mathcal{F}$. Ie: $∃ \, A ∈ \mathcal{F} \qquad  \; X ∈ P (A) \; . \tag{\checkmark}$
>   Inserting our
>   analysis of the statement $X ∈ P (A)$ from Example 2.3.3, we get $∃\, A ∈
> \mathcal{F} \; \qquad ∀ \, y \,(y ∈ X → y ∈ A). \qquad \blacksquare$

The second sentence of the solution says: $X \in P(A), \color{green}{ \text{ for some $A \in \mathcal{F}$   }} \iff \color{green}{∃ \, A ∈ \mathcal{F}} \qquad  \; X ∈ P (A)$.

$1.$ Predicated on (the green part) of this question, I'm asking if in general:

$\text{ ... for some ♦ } \qquad$  is the same as $\qquad \text{ There exists ♦ } \qquad$

$2.$ What can ♦ be?

**Supplementary dated Mar 9 2014:**  Is there any mathematical proof that "there exists" and "for some" are synonyms? I can brook this equivalence concerning the English language, but I'm anxious about it for math, though I can't pinpoint why?

Comment: Would the downvoter please divulge his/her reasons?

Comment: "For some […]" is informal, while "$\exists" is formal. Of course it says the same thing. As for the second question, you might want to go back to basics : what is a formula in a given language ?

Comment: there is a moderator!

Answer (score 1):

(1). Yes. (2) anything that fits the sentence, typically something of the form "$a \in X$" or "$a \in X$ such that $\dots$" (or just "$a$", or "$a$ such that $\dots$" if it's clear what set $a$ should be coming from anyway).

Comment: +1. Thank you very much. Would you please enlarge on $1.$ in your answer? How are these clauses equivalent? Why one instead of the other and vice versa?

Comment: You're welcome. There is not really anything to say more at (1) than "Yes". If you'd write out the statement in symbolic logic, they'd become literally the same. Which one to use is a matter of style, diversity in writing, preference.

Comment: Thank you again. Would you please explain how to express $\text{ ... for some ♦ }$ in symbolic logic, in your answer and not as a comment?

Comment: What do you mean? It is already expressed in symbolic logic in the question ($\exists A \in {\mathcal F}. X \in {\cal P}(A))$.

Comment: Thank you again. I beg leave for your patience. I'm still bewildered. Where exactly is $\text{ ... for some ♦ }$ expressed therein? I only see $\text{ There exists ♦ }$ therein, in the form $\exists \, A \in F$?

Comment: In the $\exists A \in {\cal F}$ as well. The phrases "there exists" and "for some" are synonyms.

Comment: Thank you again. Is there any mathematical proof that "there exists" and "for some" are synonyms? I'm aware of this truth in the English language, but I'm tentative about it for math, though I can't pinpoint why?