# How to Analyze $x \in \bigcup\{P(A) | A \in F\}$ logically?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing

This is from Velleman's How to Prove It.

$F$ is a family of sets. $P(A)$ is the power set of $A$.

The book says: "This time we start by writing out the deﬁnition of union. According to this deﬁnition, the statement means that x is an element of at least one of the sets $P(A)$, for $A \in F$. In other words, $\exists A \in F(x \in P (A))$. Inserting our analysis of the statement $x \in P(A)$ from Example 2.3.3, we get $\exists A \in F\forall y(y \in x \to y \in A)$."

I understand that $x$, if it belongs to the union of $P(A)$, must also exist inside of a set in $P(A)$, with $A$ belonging to $F$. But what I don't understand is how $\exists A \in F(x \in P (A))$ suffices the English form. The union definition means to essentially concatenate the subsets of all $P(A)$ from the $A \in F$ into one large non-redundant set.

This explanation of union on the previous page was very helpful: $$\bigcup F =\{ 1,2,3,4\}\cup\{2,3,4,5\}\cup\{3,4,5,6\}=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$$

But then why does he make $x \in P (A)$ when the items in the union of $P(A)$ are all integers? Wouldn't doing $x \in P(A)$ imply that $x$ is a set? In addition, belonging to the union of a set would mean that, ultimately, only $A$ matters because the elements of the sets in $P(A)$ all belong to $A$?

Edit: this is not a duplicate of the other question because I have tangential, more general questions about sets.

Edit 2: one more question. How can $x\in \mathcal{P}(A)$ ? Isn't $x$ an integer?

Edit 3: in the linked thread, many commenters noted that $x \in \mathcal P(A)$ rather than $x \in A$. But how is this true? I understand this from the logic/definition point of view. But if you take the union of a family of sets and write them out in their elements, then it would have to be literally anything other than a set. How does this work?

Comment: Please use MathJax to format math here, it looks much better than throwing around unicode characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you go from $x\in\cup\{\mathcal{P}(A)|A\in\mathcal{F}\}$ to $\exists A\in\mathcal{F}(x\in \mathcal{P}(A))$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184844/how-do-you-go-from-x-in-cup-mathcalpaa-in-mathcalf-to-exists-a-in)

Comment: @Henrik sorry about the formatting. I'm an incoming freshmen (studying CS) so learning MathJax/LaTeX is on my priority list. Almost there!

Comment: The linked topic is super old, and I need 50 points to comment. So please keep this thread open. An answer from that thread states: From 
x∈∪{P(A)|A∈F} you can conclude that there is an A∈F such that x∈P(A). The x is a subset of A and (not necessarily) an element of A. This falls under my question of shouldn't x be an element of A because the operations applied are: creating the set from power sets of A, which belong to F, and then forming the union of that set? So if x belongs to the union, then shouldn't it be an integer that belongs to A?

Comment: In general $\cup a:=\{c\mid \exists b[c\in b\wedge b\in a]\}$ so that $x\in\cup a\iff\exists b\in a[x\in b]$. Another notation for $\cup a$ is $\bigcup_{b\in a}b$. Are you aware of this?

Comment: Yeah. This is the same definition Velleman provides. Why did you say $x \in \cup a \iff \exists b \in  a[x \in b]$, specifically why the $\iff$?

Comment: Never mind, I got it. $\iff$ means that they're equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not completely understand your question/s, but I hope this helps you.

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of sets. Example: $\mathcal{F}=\{\{a,b\}, \{c,d\}\}$. It has 2 elements.

Then $\{\mathcal{P}(A)|A\in \mathcal{F}\}$ is a family of sets of sets. For our example, $\{\mathcal{P}(A)|A\in \mathcal{F}\}=\{ \{\emptyset, \{a\}, \{b\},\{a,b\}\},\{ \emptyset, \{c\},\{d\} ,\{c,d\}\}\}$ (please parse this carefully). It still has 2 elements.

Then, $\bigcup \{\mathcal{P}(A)|A\in \mathcal{F}\}$ will just become a set of sets. As you already know, union shatters the "family" by "concatenating" all "family members". For our example, $\bigcup \{\mathcal{P}(A)|A\in \mathcal{F}\}=\{ \emptyset, \{a\}, \{b\},\{a,b\},\{c\},\{d\},\{c,d\}\}$. Now 8 elements.

Now, from our example, if $x\in \bigcup \{\mathcal{P}(A)|A\in \mathcal{F}\}$, then $x$ should be a set! $x$ is not an element of some $A$, but a *subset* of it. Hence, $x$ should be an element of $\mathcal{P}(A)$ (Understand that the set $\{c\}$ is *different* from the element $c$).

Comment: Oh I see now. Thanks for writing this out. I probably should’ve just done that.